# how to clear data of datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am using dataGrid of WPF and populating through bservableCollection.

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> items = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
```

Now, for clean/clear the datagrid to use it again I used

```
  dataGrid.items.Clear();
```

but data are still showing and active in the table.

Comment: I dont know the names of methods but search for datagrid.save() and datagrid.bind() after datagrid.clear()

Comment: You should be manipulating your data, not your UI (grid). Clear the `items` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have bind collection so, in WPF you have to clean collection then it will clean data grid because you have used observable collection.

Answer (score 0):

to clear the rows of the DataGrid use:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource=null;
```

to clear the columns:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

> Now, for clean/clear the datagrid to use it again I used
>     `dataGrid.items.Clear();`

After that clear, try to bind a empty Collection.

`dataGrid.ItemsSource = tmpCollectionThatIsNull;`

And then refresh the Grid

`dataGrid.Items.Refresh();`

That should do the trick.